# Slot machine: Multiple IFs formula parsing error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

am learning excel on my own and encountered an issue with this formula.

[image]

I’m trying to simulate a slot machine random number kinda thing, where:
-if you have no same number, you lose.
-if you have 2 same numbers, you win $6
-if you have 3 same numbers you win $31
-if you have all 4 same numbers, you win $61

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3,IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0)) = 2, “You win $6”, IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3,IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0)) = 3, “You win $31”, IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3, IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0)) = 4, “You win $61”, “Thanks for playing, you win nothing”)))
```

Don’t know what went wrong and it gives me an error saying ‘formula parse error’.

Comment: Try `=IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3,IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0))=2, "You win $6", IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3,IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0))=3, "You win $31", IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3, IFERROR(MODE(B3:E3), 0))=4, "You win $61", "Thanks for playing, you win nothing")))` which is essentially the same as your original one but without the spaces in front and after the equal sign `=`, and changed the quotation marks from `“` and `”` to `"`.

Comment: @Terry W it worked! Thank you for the help! Didn’t know “” could cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative approach for your information:

```
=CHOOSE(AGGREGATE(14,4,COUNTIF(B3:E3,B3:E3),1),"Thanks for playing, you win nothing","You win $6","You win $31","You win $61")
```

> **COUNTIF** will count how many times each number as appeared in the range, **AGGREGATE** function will return the largest number of appearances, and **CHOOSE** function will return the desired terminology based on each of the four different outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option ;

```
="You "&CHOOSE(MAX(FREQUENCY(B3:E3,B3:E3)),"lose","win $6","win $31","win $61")
```